# Rules for Integral Test for Convergence/Divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose we're considering the series:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n+\sin n}{1+n^2}$$

For some reason, it seems I can't use the integral test for this problem despite the fact that it fulfills the criteria of being positive, continuous and decreasing. What exactly would the reason be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "shouldn't" use the integral test because the integral $\int \frac{x + \sin x}{x^2+1}\, dx$ is difficult.

You "can't" use the integral test because the integrand, 
$\frac{x + \sin x}{x^2+1}$, is not monotone as $x\to \infty$.

The derivative of $\frac{x + \sin x}{x^2+1}$ is $\frac{1+\cos x -2x\sin x + x^2(\cos x -1)}{(1+x^2)^2}$ which has the same sign as the numerator
$$
1+\cos x -2x\sin x + x^2(\cos x -1)
$$ When $\cos x$ is $1$ this expresion is $2$ and the integrand is *increasing*.  So the integral test does not apply.  Fortunately the limit comparison test easily gives confirmation of divergence.

---

The limit comparison test seems appropriate: $\frac{n+\sin n}{1+n^2}\sim \frac{1}{n}$.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n+\sin n}{1+n^2}}{\frac{1}{n}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+n\sin n}{1+n^2}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\sin n/n}{1/n^2+1}
=1
$$
and since $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, so does $\sum\frac{n+\sin n}{1+n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{n}{1+n^{2}}\geq\sum\dfrac{n}{n^{2}+n^{2}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum\dfrac{1}{n}=\infty$.

$\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{|\sin n|}{1+n^{2}}\leq\sum\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty$.

If it were convergent, then $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{n}{1+n^{2}}=\sum\left(\dfrac{n}{1+n^{2}}+\dfrac{\sin n}{1+n^{2}}\right)-\sum\dfrac{\sin n}{1+n^{2}}$ would be convergent, a contradiction.

Comment: I realize the ideal way to do this, but my question was as to why we cannot use the integral test. It seems to fulfill the criteria of the integral test.

Comment: But the function seems not decreasing/eventually decreasing, how do we apply Integral Test then?

Answer (score 1):

The summand can be bounded:

$n+\sin(n) \geq n-1 \geq \frac{n}{2} ~\forall n \geq 2$

$1+n^2 < 2n^2 ~\forall n \geq 1$

Therefore, the sum is lower-bounded by $\sum_n \frac{1}{4n}$ which is $\frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$, which diverges, because the harmonic series does.